# Is there an API for fetching list of countries according iso 3166-1?

Tags: reactjs, country, country-codes, countries, mobile-country-code

Is it possible to fetch a list of countries according to ISO 3166-1 ?
I have found [this package](https://github.com/annexare/Countries) (Countries), however I am not sure whether it is reliable source or not. How do you handle it ?

Also, there is a list of available countries in PDF, see [here](https://unctadstat.unctad.org/en/Classifications/DimCountries_Transcode_Iso3166-1_UnctadStat.pdf) (unctad)

I am curious whether there is a free API for this purpose, or I need to manually create a JSON for my react app.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://datahub.io/core/country-list#data-cli) is one that you can use.
end point:
`data get` `https://datahub.io/core/country-list`

Comment: It is not an http api :(